# nginx скрыть часть URL

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, rewrite

Не могу понять как скрыть часть url для пользователей.
Есть ссылки вида:

```
site.com/www/site1/index1.php
site.com/www/site2/index2.php
```

Нужно переделать сиё чудо в

```
site.com/index1.php
site.com/index2.php
```

Конфигурация такая:
`nginx (front) - nginx (back) - php-fpm`

Фронт проксирующий:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_pass              http://172.18.1.1:1234;
}
```

Бэк работает через сокет:

```
location / {                                             
  try_files           $uri $uri/ =404;         
}                                                                                                                  

location ~ \.php$ {                                                        
  include             fastcgi_params;                                    
  fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;                        
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;                                             
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;                                             
}
```

Затупок мой в том, что я не понимаю как сделать, чтоб для нескольких директорий `php` отрабатывал. Т.е. конструкция данного вида не работоспособна:

```
location / {                                             
  try_files           $uri $uri/ =404;         
}                                                

location ~ /www/site1/\.php$ {                                                                  
  root /dir/to/www/site1;                                               
  include             fastcgi_params;          
  fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;                        
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;                                             
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;                                             
}     

...                                                                     

location ~ \.php$ {                                                        
  include             fastcgi_params;                                    
  fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;                        
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;                                             
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;                                             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задачу решил таким кодом

```
rewrite ^/www/site1/$ /test1/ last;           

location ~ /test1/(.*\.php)$ {                   

  alias /app/www/site1/$1;                  

  include             fastcgi_params;          
  fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;                        
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;                                             
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;                                             
}
```